# C++ What is the point of using const in a class setter function?

Tags: c++, constants

I am going through a text book to freshen up my (fairly bad) C++ knowledge and I came across this code example (shortened):

```
class MyClass{
private:
    int count;
    double price;
    string name;
public:
    void setValues(const int&, const double&, const string&);
};


void MyClass::setValues(const int& c, const double& p, const string& n){
    count = c;
    price = p;
    name= n;
}

int main(){
    myClass pOne;
    pOne.setValues(5, 0.75, "Kiwi");

    return 0;
}
```

The Way I understand the `const` keyword and the way it was described  in the book thus far is that I can use it to declare constants, which should not be subject to change. This is better for the compiler since it knows that the values won't change.

But here I use const every time I set values

```
void MyClass::setValues(const int& a, const double& p, const string& b)
```

once the values of pOne are set, I can change them over and over with the setValues function, so what is the point of making them const?

Comment: It's so you don't change the thing the reference refers to.

Comment: if the text book does not explain that then you need a better book.

Comment: try to modify `a` or `p` or `b`. You'll get a compiler error. Then remove the `const` and try again. Then consider if it makes sense for a setter to modify its parameters

Comment: They are const-references, it is a technique to avoid passing possibly heavy structures by value (copy). Doesn't make much sense for primitive types like `double`, and also even if you pass some bigger structure, like `std::string` by value, the compilers are usually smart enough to not make a copy anyway (if it's not needed).

Comment: Passing `const int& a` rather than just `int a` (pass by value) probably leads to worse code-generation by the compiler.

Comment: `const int&` and `const double&` are anti-patterns.  Pass primitives by value, it's more efficient.

Comment: "*the way it was described in the book thus far is that I can use [`const`] to declare constants, which should not be subject to change*" - that is *one* use of `const`, yes. It is not the only use, though. There are at least 2 other uses of `const` I can think of - declaring a (reference/pointer to) a `const` object (as this code is doing), and `const`-qualifying a class method so its body code can't modify the object it is being called on.

Answer (score 1):

> once the values of pOne are set, I can change them over and over with the setValues function, so what is the point of making them const?

This is flawed logic. Consider this small example:

```
const int x = 42;
int y = x;
```

The value of `x` is assigned to `y`. Just because `x` is constant does not imply that `y` is too. You can change the value of `y` afterwards.

In the function signature the `const` means the usual: You cannot modify the parameters. It would be odd if a setter would change them.

```
struct foo {
   int value = 42;
   void set(int& x) { 
      value = x; 
      x = 42;          // what ?!?
   }
};
int main() {
    int a = 2;
    foo f;
    f.set(x); 
    std::cout << x;   // prints 42.... what?!?
    const int b = 3;
    f.set(b);         // error because b is const :(
}
```

The setter takes its parameters by constant references because it tries to avoid a copy (hence reference) and parameters are not modified by the call (hence `const`).

Passing `int` as `const int&` however, is not really recommended, because it isn't cheaper than passing the `int` by value.